# Using Phpredis in Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7, phpredis

I have read the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/redis#phpredis).

I have changed the database.php file, once this is done I have deleted the predis package from my vendor.

```
composer remove predis/predis
```

But when I do a composer update or any artisan command I get this error:

```
In PredisConnector.php line 25:

  Class 'Predis\Client' not found
```

[image]

Why do I need predis if I am already using phpredis?

Comment: Have you removed them from app.php?

Comment: Yes, and return me another error: In PhpRedisConnector.php line 65:

  Class 'Redis' not found

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there.  The "Class 'Redis' not found" error in PhpRedisConnector.php is likely because the redis extension is not enabled in your php.ini file.  Keep in mind that sometimes CLI uses a different ini file than FPM.  Run `php --ini` to see which ini file the CLI is using and update it to enable Redis extension.